# mongodb - indexes disappear after few minutes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Have tested this on MongoDB 3.4 and 3.6:

Create one or more indexes in a collection

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.coll.createIndex({checkinDate:1}, {background:1})
{
  "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
  "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
  "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
  "ok" : 1,
  "operationTime" : Timestamp(1518162276, 2),
  "$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1518162276, 2),
    "signature" : {
      "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
      "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
    }
  }
}
```

Now list the indexes.

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.coll.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "cico.coll"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "checkinDate" : 1
                },
                "name" : "checkinDate_1",
                "ns" : "cico.coll",
                "background" : 1
        }
]
```

Wait for some time (few mins)

List the indexes again:

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.coll.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "cico.coll"
        }
]
```

I have no clue why these indexes created are getting deleted? Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is actually a non-issue. there was a program, running in the background, which was dropping all the indexes (for a completely different reason).

Answer (score 2):

this is actually a non-issue. there was a program, running in the background, which was dropping all the indexes periodically (for a completely different reason).

Answer (score 1):

Index option `background` is of type `boolean`, try:

```
db.coll.createIndex (
   { checkinDate:1 }, { background: true }
 )
```

Comment: It did not help. Specifying background:1, background: true, or not specifying background at all -- the same results. (btw, thanks for your input).

Comment: @rsmoorthy, ntw. Anything in the `mongod.log` as the index build will be logged...

Comment: Thanks @N3i1. the logs from docker (poorly configured) was not user friendly, so I did not check that at all. Thanks to your nudge, I went and checked and found that there was another program that was dropping all the indexes on a periodic basis! :-(  I feel so stupid now.

Comment: @rsmoorthy glad your all sorted. You might find the `background` boolean value of use now :-)